# How to scrape "markup"-text from html code

Tags: python, web-scraping

I would like to scrape text from a website using Beautifulsoup.

From the code which can be seen in the screenshot above, I would like to retrieve the text stored under `markup="content"`.

I know how to retrieve all markup-parts using `soup.find("div", class_="break-word news_main")`. But I don't know how to only access the `markup="content"`-part.

Help would be very much appreciated :)

(Also, is markup a special term in html like "class" or "id"? What does "markup" mean?)

[image: Picture of html code]

Answer (score 2):

`soup.find_all(markup="content")`, as you can see you can filter by any attribute. See [docs](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#searching-the-tree) for more details. `markup` is some kind of custom attribute; it's not a valid attribute for `div` elements but you can technically have any attribute on an element and it will still work, both in HTML and in BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `soup.find_all(markup='content')` or a different syntax is `soup.find_all('div', {'markup': 'content'}` which will give you all divs that contain the attribute mark up with a value of content.

Markup can mean quite a few things. It's basically a system for stylizing text. You can see more [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language) In this context it's probably something used to style html on a webpage.